# Circular one-to-one model save call with presence validations on both sides

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, factory-bot

Given there is a `Foo` and `Bar` models with `one-to-one` relationship and each other presence validation:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :foo_bar
  has_one :bar, through: :foo_bar, inverse_of: :foo

  validates :bar, presence: true
end

class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :bar
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :foo_bar
  has_one :foo, through: :foo_bar, inverse_of: :bar

  validates :foo, presence: true
end
```

And factories for them:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    foo_bar
    bar { |foo| build(:bar, foo_bar: foo_bar, foo: foo) }
  end

  factory :bar do
    foo_bar
    foo { |bar| build(:foo, foo_bar: foo_bar, bar: bar) }
  end

  factory :foo_bar do
  end
end
```

When I try to create an instance of either `Foo` or `Bar` with   `FactoryGirl.create(:foo)` I got `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`.

The reason of this is that:

1. When saving `foo` object it looks at the associated `bar`
2. A-ha! `bar` is not saved, we need to save it first
3. While saving `bar` it looks at `foo` (which is not saved yet) and
   decides to save it
4. and so on it tries to save each other which leads to infinity loop

One solution is to add `autosave: false` on one of the ends of association like:

```
class Bar 
  has_one :foo, through: :foo_bar, inverse_of: :bar, autosave: false
end
```

This allow to create `Foo` but prevents `create(:bar)` because `foo` association will not be saved which leads to invalid `Bar` record (because of validation).

How it can be fixed so both `foo` and `bar` factories would be valid?

Comment: Could you explain why you'd use such a relationship rather than `has_one` & `belongs_to`? It seems complicated using an extra model instead of an extra field.

Comment: @TheChamp it sounds reasonable but I'm still interested in solving the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a conceptual problem. Consider this - you're in a foreign country and you lost your documents. You go to your embassy and they want to see your plane tickets to issue a new passport. You go to the airline and they want your passport to issue a copy of the tickets. It's a deadlock, a chicken-and-egg problem.

The only way to solve the problem is to redefine it. You can decide that you want to validate the relationship, but for at least one of the directions, you will validate only after it's created.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :foo_bar
  has_one :bar, through: :foo_bar, inverse_of: :foo

  validates :bar, presence: true, on: :update
end
```

So, in our example, the airline will still not issue you your tickets without a passport, but the embassy will give you the passport without the tickets. Additionally, if you already have the passport and go to the embassy for any reason, they will ask to see the tickets to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I think `validates :foo, presence: true` ends up using `validates_associated`.

Documenation states: **Don't use validates_associated on both ends of your associations. They would call each other in an infinite loop.**

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-associated.

basically, one must be a follower... maybe you could explain your use-case and get some data-model feedback as well?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the model structure seems off. The best solution is to probably achieve what you want through a different association. However, if that is not an option, I will throw out an idea that might get you somewhere.

You can overwrite autosave and check for presence yourself. You will still need to have one depend on the other but you could do something like this in your Foo model:

```
def autosave_associated_records_for_bar
  #validate data
  #save bar
  #probably need to save ids on foobar
end
```

Note: You should be careful when doing this and really make sure you understand the effects (validators may not be run etc)

You can check out more on AutosaveAssociation in the source code here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb

Maybe something in there will be helpful.